# Trying to create a table using xtable giving result iside html tags

Tags: r, xtable

Im trying to create an elegant table as described [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/elegant-correlation-table-using-xtable-r-package) but I get the result inside html tags instead of a table.

```
library(xtable)
# x is a matrix containing the data
# method : correlation method. "pearson"" or "spearman"" is supported
# removeTriangle : remove upper or lower triangle
# results :  if "html" or "latex"
  # the results will be displayed in html or latex format
corstars <-function(x, method=c("pearson", "spearman"), removeTriangle=c("upper", "lower"),
                     result=c("none", "html", "latex")){
    #Compute correlation matrix
    require(Hmisc)
    x <- as.matrix(x)
    correlation_matrix<-rcorr(x, type=method[1])
    R <- correlation_matrix$r # Matrix of correlation coeficients
    p <- correlation_matrix$P # Matrix of p-value 
    
    ## Define notions for significance levels; spacing is important.
    mystars <- ifelse(p < .0001, "****", ifelse(p < .001, "*** ", ifelse(p < .01, "**  ", ifelse(p < .05, "*   ", "    "))))
    
    ## trunctuate the correlation matrix to two decimal
    R <- format(round(cbind(rep(-1.11, ncol(x)), R), 2))[,-1]
    
    ## build a new matrix that includes the correlations with their apropriate stars
    Rnew <- matrix(paste(R, mystars, sep=""), ncol=ncol(x))
    diag(Rnew) <- paste(diag(R), " ", sep="")
    rownames(Rnew) <- colnames(x)
    colnames(Rnew) <- paste(colnames(x), "", sep="")
    
    ## remove upper triangle of correlation matrix
    if(removeTriangle[1]=="upper"){
      Rnew <- as.matrix(Rnew)
      Rnew[upper.tri(Rnew, diag = TRUE)] <- ""
      Rnew <- as.data.frame(Rnew)
    }
    
    ## remove lower triangle of correlation matrix
    else if(removeTriangle[1]=="lower"){
      Rnew <- as.matrix(Rnew)
      Rnew[lower.tri(Rnew, diag = TRUE)] <- ""
      Rnew <- as.data.frame(Rnew)
    }
    
    ## remove last column and return the correlation matrix
    Rnew <- cbind(Rnew[1:length(Rnew)-1])
    if (result[1]=="none") return(Rnew)
    else{
      if(result[1]=="html") print(xtable(Rnew), type="html")
      else print(xtable(Rnew), type="latex") 
    }
} 
corstars(mtcars[,1:7], result="html")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** See comments @Marco_CH (many thanks!)

```
htmlTable::htmlTable(corstars(mtcars[,1:7], result="html"))
```

**First answer:**
Something like this?

```
table1 <- corstars(mtcars[,1:7])

print(htmlTable::htmlTable(table1,useViewer=TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Just one thing: `htmlTable::htmlTable(corstars(mtcars[,1:7], result="html"))` looks a bit better.

Comment: Ok. Many thanks I will update!